# Modulation in laser satellite communication

Tags: digital-communications, qpsk, bpsk, fsk

In small satellite communication technique we can use optical spectrum (optical (laser) communication system). The common and simplest modulation techniques used are On and Off
keying (OOK), Q-ary PPM (Quaternary Pulse Position modulation) and Frequency Shift
Keying (FSK).

Could someone explain why the PSK - modulations (BPSK, QPSK) could be not used in the optic communication in satellite?

Comment: *Could someone explain why the PSK - modulations (BPSK, QPSK) could be not used in the optic communication in satellite?* We can; as in any other communication, you just need to stabilize the phase. So, that claim seems to be wrong.

Comment: *What is a difference between FSK (BFSK) and PSK(BPSK)* Completely independent question and should be asked separately. Also, both terms are researchable!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have read the current reseach and device specifications. Most of them use OOK NRZ modulation and I havent seen any with PSk

Comment: but you say "why we couldn't". And we can: Do you mean "why commercial transceivers don't do this" (and please link to a few of them)? I'm trying to nail down exactly what your question is! (also, if the question is "why do commercial systems not do what is technically possible", then the usual answer is "no profit, sorry".)

Comment: also, TESAT seems to be behind the [European Data Relay System](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6934556), which is a ground-to-satellite coherent optical link that's commercially available as "TESAT Laser Communication Terminal" and does PSK.

Comment: @Adil.Kolenko Any modulation based on phase information is difficult to implement in an optical link, because photodiodes detect power, and hence lose all phase information. Lately, researchers have come up with workarounds to this problem and some PSK systems have become available.

Comment: @MBaz well in fiber-optical systems, coherent transmission is definitely state-of-the-art; 2011 was the first commercial submarine cable tryout, and, well, that's 10 years ago.